# Trying to create single css file for single sass file (as well as using multiple sass file to one css file) with Grunt

Tags: css, compilation, sass, gruntjs

I have a project which is using a standard setup of using multiple sass files and partials which are compiled to a single global css file.

I now need the functionality to also have single sass files map to single css files (these are components/widgets).

So in my final markup a widget will have something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/widgets/widget-name.css"/>
```

I've tried a few options in my gruntfile. Current set up looks like this:

```
 sass: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                style: 'compressed'
            },
            files: {
                 "Webcontent/css/site.css": "WebContent/source/sass/site.scss"
            }
        } 
    },
    watch: {
        src: {
            files: ['WebContent/source/sass/*.scss'],
            tasks: ['sass'],
        }
    }
```

I've tried the following:

```
sass: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                style: 'compressed'
            },
            files: {
                 "Webcontent/css/site.css": "WebContent/source/sass/site.scss",
                 "Webcontent/css/widgets/*.css": "WebContent/source/sass/widgets/*.scss",
            }
        } 
    },
```

As well as:

```
sass: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                style: 'compressed'
            },

            files: [
                {src: 'WebContent/source/sass/site.scss', dest: 'Webcontent/css/site.css'},
                {src: 'WebContent/source/sass/widgets/*.scss', dest: 'Webcontent/css/widgets/*.css' },
              ],
        } 
    },
    watch: {
        src: {
            files: ['WebContent/source/sass/*.scss', 'WebContent/source/sass/widgets/*.scss'],
            tasks: ['sass'],
        }
    }
```

I keep getting the error in grunt: Warning: `Warning: Unable to write "Webcontent/css/widgets/*.css" file (Error code: ENOENT
).`

Surely I don't have to specifiy a destination css file?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compile all files within a folder you can do this:

```
sass: {
    dist: {
        files: [
          {
            expand: true, // Recursive
            cwd: "WebContent/source/sass", // The startup directory
            src: ["**/*.scss"], // Source files
            dest: "Webcontent/css", // Destination
            ext: ".css" // File extension 
          }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: But I still need to map `source/sass/main.scss` to `css/main.css`

Comment: What you mean by map?

Comment: I require the current setup of multiple SASS files to one CSS file, as well as the option to create a single css file for any sass file from the widgets subfolder. So the two should be treated as separate tasks.

Comment: Only files **without** a prefix of an underscore can be compiled into a separate CSS file.  If your widgets aren't prefixed with an underscore then the code above will compile them all into seperate CSS files.  Your `main.scss` will have `@import`'s of your widgets and will compile to a single file.  Give it a try.

Comment: OK thank you. That is working only I have to put all my css files in one folder.

Comment: The Sass files can be in separate folders but under the folder specified in `cwd`.  So you could set that to a high level and it will catch everything.

Comment: OK thank you. I would still like to know if it is possible to set this up as two separate tasks.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your first solution and on http://ryanchristiani.com/getting-started-with-grunt-and-sass/, your "watched" files should more likely look like this:

(not sure if it really makes a difference, but better give it a try)

```
watch: {
  src: {
    files: 'WebContent/source/sass/*.scss',
    tasks: ['sass'],
  }
}
```

---

**Otherwise**, it is usually easier to build your *Gruntfile.js* this way:

(only *main.scss* is compiled and all the other *.scss* files are `@import` into this *main.scss*)

```
watch: {
  sass: {
    files: './assets/css/sass/*.scss',
    tasks: ['sass', 'cssmin']
  }
},
sass: require( './assets/custom_modules/sass.js' ).task,
cssmin: require( './assets/custom_modules/cssmin.js' ).task
```

Then in **sass.js**

```
exports.task = {
  dist: {
    options: {
      style: 'expanded',
      lineNumbers: true,
      sourcemap: 'none'
    },
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'assets/css/sass/',
      src: [ 'main.scss' ],
      dest: 'assets/css/',
      ext: '.css'
    }]
  }
};
```

Hope it could help.

Good Luck'

Comment: @lharby Any feedback would be appreciate. Does the quick fix make any difference? Might interest me as well.

Comment: I tried Colin Bacons answer and it does work although I had to slightly change my workflow. So I still want to know if it is possible to create two separate tasks for different folders of files. I am sure this must be a possibility.